# Center a Bootstrap button in the navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have a button called Login which is in the navbar but it's positioned near the top and I would like to have it centered in the navbar. When a user logs in, there is also a button called Logout near the top as well so I hope I can use your solution to fix this. This is my code for my header:

```html
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class=container>
            <div class=navbar-header>
                <button type=button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle=collapse data-target=#navbar aria-expanded=false aria-controls=navbar>
                    <span class=sr-only>Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class=icon-bar></span>
                    <span class=icon-bar></span>
                    <span class=icon-bar></span>
                </button>
                <!-- <a class=navbar-brand href=<?= site_url() ?>><?= $this->config->item('app_name')?></a> -->
                <a class=navbar-brand href=<?= site_url() ?>><img src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>resources/imgs/logo.png" height="30"></a>
            </div>
            <div id=navbar class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['user_login'])): ?>
                    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <a href=<?= site_url() ?>login class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Login</a>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                        <a href=<?= site_url() ?>logout class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class=<?= $sell_active ?>><a href=<?= site_url() ?>sell><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></span> Sell</a></li>
                    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_login'])): ?>
                        <li class=<?= $myorders_active ?>>
                            <a href=<?= site_url() ?>myorders><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> My Orders</a>
                        </li>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <li class=<?= $track_active ?>>
                            <a href=<?= site_url() ?>track><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Order Status</a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])): ?>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <li class=<?= $register_active ?>>
                            <a href=<?= site_url() ?>register><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Register</a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Mainly question CSS not codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Are you locking for something like that?

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);

}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>
    Login
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I would like.

Comment: Nice glad i could help you XD

Comment: I pasted my current code for my header, do you mind editing it so it will work like the one you showed me?

Comment: Well your code has no styling at all and the editor doesn't understand php. Just look at my example all you need to do is apply position relative to your header and than move your buttons with top and transform into position i think you can do that XD

Comment: @Jay Up-vote for the answer that solved your purpose.